# Swift Package Manager with Xcode - Could not build Objective-C module

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a swift executable package that has a dependency on objective-c library package. I'm trying to use Xcode for executable package development but I'm getting `Could not build Objective-C module 'objcpackage'` error while editing the swift file which imports objective-c module. Compiling works both from Xcode and also directly from command line using `swift build` but as soon as I open the swift file with import of that objc package the error pops up.
I have used the SPM to generate xcodeproj.

Clean nor clean build directory, deleting generated module map from the xcodeproj or restarting Xcode did not help.

I have created Objective-C package with the following:

`$ swift package init --type library`

It contains only one header `Sources/include/Foo.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo: NSObject
@end
```

and one `.m` file:

```
#import "Foo.h"

@implementation Foo
@end
```

The Swift package was created with `$ swift package init --type executable`.

The `Package.swift` file looks like:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "swiftpackage", 
    dependencies: [ .Package(url: "../objcpackage", majorVersion: 1) ]
)
```

The `main.swift` contains only:

```
import objcpackage
```

Xcode project was created with `$ swift package generate-xcodeproj`

Xcode Version: `8.2.1 (8C1002)`

Swift Version: `3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)`

How can I get rid of that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug that was recently fixed in the package manager (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3121). Have you tried a recent snapshot from https://swift.org/download/?

I tested the package you describe with a recent version of Swift 3.1 and it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you! With latest snapshot (`3.1-dev (LLVM a7c680da51, Clang df9f12fda6, Swift 7cc03a3925)`) the error is gone.